# Combine 2 different custom post slugs into a single permalink?

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting

Need some help with this URL rewrite.
I have 2 custom posts set up, 'company' and 'job'. I have a single-company page, and a single-job page, which work fine. A company can have many jobs, and I'm managing the relation between jobs and company using post meta.

Single company URL is `http://..../company/abc-intl`, and single job url is `http://..../job/photoshop-designer`.

I want a single job URL to include the slug of the company it belongs to/is related with. So for above example, it should be 
    `http://..../company/abc-intl/job/photoshop-designer`.

I tried a lot with 'add_rewrite_rule', 'add_rewrite_tag', but didn't seem to work. Please any ideas on how to achieve this URL?

Comment: Thanks for viewing! I got it done with a lot of trial and errors! (bump sounds too rude!)

Comment: Cool... Got a down vote for this! Dunno why!

Comment: It would be useful if you actually shared your solution in an answer. (I'm not the one who downvoted)

Comment: Ohh! Thought so! Sure, lemme compile the solution in a proper format...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution if anyone comes across such a 'weird' requirement ;)
Also, when the job CPT (or any CPT you want to associate) is published, you need to save the id of the company CPT (whose slug will be used for forming the other part of the permalink) as a post meta for the job.

```
<?php
add_filter('init', 'add_page_rewrite_rules');
function add_page_rewrite_rules(){
    global $wp_rewrite, $wp;

    add_rewrite_rule('^company/([^/]+)/job/([^/]+)', 'index.php?company=$matches[1]&job=$matches[2]', 'top');
    $job_structure = '/job/%job%';
    $wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag("%job%", '([^/]+)', "job=");
    $wp_rewrite->add_permastruct('job', $job_structure, false);

}

add_filter('post_type_link', 'job_permalink', 10, 3);
function job_permalink($permalink, $post_id, $leavename) {
    $post = get_post($post_id);
    $rewritecode = array(
    '%job%',
    'job'
    );

    if ( '' != $permalink && !in_array($post->post_status, array('draft', 'pending', 'auto-draft')) ) {
        job_link = '';
        if ( strpos($permalink, 'job') !== false ) {
            $company_id = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'job_company_id', true);
            $company = basename(get_permalink($company_id));
            $job_link = 'company'.'/'.$company;
        }

        $rewritereplace = array(
                                    $post->post_name,
                                    $job_link.'/job'
                        );
        $permalink = str_replace($rewritecode, $rewritereplace, $permalink);
    } 
    else { 
        // if they're not using the fancy permalink option
    }
    return $permalink;
}
?>
```

Hope this helps someone! You can contact me if stuck while implementing this.